# How to define secondary key while table creation?

Tags: cassandra, cql3, cqlsh, database, nosql

I was trying to create a secondary index in `cassandra` using `cql3`. I know I can do it using `CREATE INDEX..` syntax.

But **is there any way I can designate a column as `Secondary key` when using `CREATE TABLE..` syntax** i.e., while defining a table?

I have searched on internet but getting results regarding `CREATE INDEX`. I'm not sure how to frame it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. You have to do two queries. You can do them one after the other.